# Capture Stderr and redirect it to Stdout in service with goroutine in go

Tags: go, pipe, channel, goroutine

I need to write a service calling a black box function. That function may produce errors pushed to Stderr. I need to intercept them and print them immediately. The code below outlines the general idea.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

func doMagic(i int) {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "%d stderr\n", i)
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan struct{})
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    var wr, r *os.File
    i := 0
    go func() {
        for {
            ch <- struct{}{}
            i += 1

            doMagic(i)

            wr.Close()
            size, _ := io.Copy(&buf, r)
            if size != 0 {
                fmt.Printf("Size: %d, Content: %s", size, buf.String())
            } else {
                fmt.Println("Empty")
            }
        }
    }()
    for {
        r, wr, _ = os.Pipe()
        os.Stderr = wr
        <-ch
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't work as expected. I expect that the first iteration of the "for" loop within the goroutine should print the size and content of the first error message generated by the `doMagic` functions. Instead, it prints "Empty." Why does this occur, and how can I fix it? How to change the code to print errors from the "DoMagic" function immediately? How can I prevent the creation of a new Pipe and the subsequent closure of its write channel on each loop iteration?

**UPD (03-19-2024)**

It requires the buffer reset:

```
...
        size, _ := io.Copy(&buf, r)
        if size != 0 {
            fmt.Printf("Size: %d, Content: %s", size, buf.String())
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Empty")
        }
        buf.Reset()  // reset the buffer
...
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a pipe to capture os.Stderr. Copy pipe to a buffer in a goroutine. Run the magic function. Cleanup.

```
func run(i int) {
    r, w, _ := os.Pipe()

    // Capture stderr. Restore on return from the function.
    stderr := os.Stderr
    os.Stderr = w
    defer func() {
        os.Stderr = stderr
    }()

    // Copy catured stderr to a buffer.
    done := make(chan *bytes.Buffer)
    go func() {
        defer r.Close()
        var buf bytes.Buffer
        io.Copy(&buf, r)
        done <- &buf
    }()

    doMagic(i)

    // Cause io.Copy to exit by closing the write end of the pipe.
    w.Close()

    // Wait for goroutine to complete.
    buf := <-done

    fmt.Printf("Size: %d, Content: %s", buf.Len(), buf.String())

}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/bHwd9X_QWPy

To print immediately, use an io.MultiWriter to write to the original stderr and the buffer:

```
// Copy catured stderr to a buffer and to the original stderr.
done := make(chan *bytes.Buffer)
go func() {
    defer r.Close()
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    io.Copy(io.MultiWriter(&buf, stderr), r)
    done <- &buf
}()
```

https://go.dev/play/p/egDsSLuFwOV